# How to update "HasMultipleValues" for Sharepoint 2013 Metadata Managed Property through Powershell

Tags: powershell, properties, metadata, managed, sharepoint-2013

I need to add new Managed Metadata Property into Sharepoint 2013 using Powershell + Sharepoint Powershell Extensions.

I did this using C#.

To get all Sharepoint Managed properties I made this:

```
 private static string GetAllSPManagedProperties(string searchApplication)
        {
            RunspaceConfiguration config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            PSSnapInException OExSnapIn = null;
            PSSnapInInfo pssnap = config.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell", out OExSnapIn);
            //create powershell runspace
            Runspace cmdlet = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(config);
            cmdlet.Open();
            RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(cmdlet);
            // set powershell execution policy to unrestricted
            scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
            // create a pipeline and load it with command object
            Pipeline pipeline = cmdlet.CreatePipeline();
            Command cmd = new Command("Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty");
            pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);
            CommandParameter cmdParam = new CommandParameter("SearchApplication", searchApplication);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(cmdParam);
            //pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
            // this will format the output
            IEnumerable<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();
            pipeline.Stop();
            cmdlet.Close();
            // process each object in the output and append to stringbuilder  
            StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in output)
            {
                var typeNames = obj.TypeNames;

                var p1 = obj.Properties["ID"].Value;            // "AboutMe"    object {string}
                var p2 = obj.Properties["ManagedType"].Value;   // Text object {Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ManagedDataType}
                var p3 = obj.Properties["PID"].Value;           // 26           object {int}
                var p4 = obj.Properties["Name"].Value;          // "AboutMe"    object {string}
                var p5 = obj.Properties["HasMultipleValues"].Value;         // true object {bool}
                string managedTypeName = (string)p2.ToString();

                results.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }
            return results.ToString();
        }
```

The problem is that I am trying to set this flag "HasMultipleValues" of the selected Managed Metadata Property programmatically.

```
obj.Properties["HasMultipleValues"].Value =  true;
```

I do not know how to do that. I was hoping to find some Update method of the PSObject (returned by the pipeline.Invoke() but unfortunately didn't found anything useful.

My question is, Is it possible to set the properties of any ManagedMetadataProperty and how ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that I found a solution myself.

I didn't found the way on how to achieve the solution through setting object properties but have found equally acceptable solution through scripting.

```
    public static void UpdateSharepointManagedMetadataProperty(string searchApplication, string propertyName, bool HasMultipleValues)
    {
        RunspaceConfiguration config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        PSSnapInException OExSnapIn = null;
        PSSnapInInfo pssnap = config.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell", out OExSnapIn);
        //create powershell runspace
        Runspace cmdlet = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(config);
        cmdlet.Open();
        RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(cmdlet);

        bool set = HasMultipleValues;
        string script = "";
        if (set)
        {
            script =
                string.Format("$prop = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -Identity {0} -SearchApplication \"{1}\" \r\n", propertyName, searchApplication) +
                              "$prop.HasMultipleValues = $true  \r\n" +
                              "$prop.Queryable = $true  \r\n" +
                              "$prop.Refinable = $true  \r\n" +
                              "$prop.Searchable = $true  \r\n" +
                              "$prop.Retrievable = $true  \r\n" +
                              "$prop.Update()  \r\n";
        }
        else
        {
            script =
                string.Format("$prop = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -Identity {0} -SearchApplication \"{1}\" \r\n", propertyName, searchApplication) +
                              "$prop.HasMultipleValues = $false  \r\n" +
                              "$prop.Queryable = $false  \r\n" +
                              "$prop.Refinable = $false  \r\n" +
                              "$prop.Searchable = $false  \r\n" +
                              "$prop.Retrievable = $false  \r\n" +
                              "$prop.Update()  \r\n";
        }


        var result = scriptInvoker.Invoke(script);

        cmdlet.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Calling commandlets from code is not pretty. You should look at the admin API and use the proper objects imo.